# Exporting global variable from DLL to Exe

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a main function in a project which has need to get a variable from dll project in VS2022. It should be initiallized at particular moment in Init function of renderer, that is why I want to define it in cpp file. All files, except of Main.cpp, are in project that ends up being dll which is referenced by project where main function is

#### Exe project

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Engine.h"
__declspec(dllimport) int exportedVariable;
int main()
{   
    Renderer renderer;
    renderer.Init()
    std::cout << "app : " << exportedVariable << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### DLL project

Engine.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Renderer.h"
```

Renderer.h:

```
__declspec(dllexport) extern  int exportedVariable;
```

Renderer.cpp:

```
void Renderer::Init()
{
    exportedVariable = 12;
}
```

I do not get neither compiler nor linker errors, however main prints 0 instead of 12

Comment: `extern` should be on the declaration in `Main.cpp` and not on the declaration in `Renderer.h`.

Comment: If there any reason to expect `Renderer::Init` to be run? Globals are zero-initialized even without explicit initialization.

Comment: if extern is on Main.cpp then there is redefenition error of exportedVariable in Renderer.cpp. My bad, Renderer::Init is called later in code before printing - I forgot to put it, edited question

Comment: `int exportedVariable;` in `Renderer.cpp`. `extern` + `dllexport`/`dllimport` in `Renderer.h` and `Main.cpp`

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! I guess we should put `extern` before `dllexport/dllimport` to let c++ know where definition is coming from?